# Can a string be returned from a Bash function without using echo or global variables?

Tags: bash, function, return, echo, interactive

I'm returning to a lot of Bash scripting at my work, and I'm rusty.

Is there a way to return a local value string from a function without making it global or using echo? I want the function to be able to interact with the user via screen, but also pass a return value to a variable without something like `export return_value="return string"`. The printf command seems to respond exactly like echo.

For example:

```
function myfunc() {
    [somecommand] "This appears only on the screen"
    echo "Return string"
}

# return_value=$(myfunc)
This appears only on the screen

# echo $return_value
Return string
```

Comment: You can find the answer [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. Bash doesn't return anything other than a numeric exit status from a function. Your choices are:

1. Set a non-local variable inside the function.
2. Use `echo`, `printf`, or similar to provide output. That output can then be assigned outside the function using command substitution.

Comment: how can you `echo` strings without it being passed as part of the result?

Comment: @qodeninja if you have a function with name foo you can run `result=$(foo)`

Answer (score 9):

To make it appear only in screen, you can redirect `echo` to stderr:

```
echo "This appears only on the screen" >&2
```

Obviously, stderr should not be redirected.

Answer (score 5):

A creative use of the `eval` function, you can also assign values to a parameters location, and effectively to your argument, within the body of a function. This is sometimes termed a "call-by-output" parameter.

```
foo() {
    local input="$1";
    # local output=$2;  # need to use $2 in scope...

    eval "${2}=\"Hello, ${input} World!\""
}


foo "Call by Output" output;

echo $output;
```

Comment: This doesn't escape `$input` or check if the variable name is valid. It _could_ be made safe but is really not worth it when one can assign to a known global, like `foo_output`, then immediately assign that value to the desired variable after the function call.