# Shell scripting return values not correct, why?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

In a shell script I wrote to test how functions are returning values I came across an odd unexpected behavior. The code below assumes that when entering the function fnttmpfile the first echo statement would print to the console and then the second echo statement would actually return the string to the calling main. Well that's what I assumed, but I was wrong!

```
#!/bin/sh

fntmpfile() {
TMPFILE=/tmp/$1.$$
echo "This is my temp file dude!"
echo "$TMPFILE"
}

mainname=main
retval=$(fntmpfile "$mainname")
echo "main retval=$retval"
```

What actually happens is the reverse. The first echo goes to the calling function and the second echo goes to STDOUT. why is this and is there a better way....

> main retval=This is my temp file dude!
>   /tmp/main.19121

The whole reason for this test is because I am writing a shell script to do some database backups and decided to use small functions to do specific things, ya know make it clean instead of spaghetti code. One of the functions I was using was this:

```
log_to_console() {
    # arg1 = calling function name
    # arg2 = message to log
    printf "$1 - $2\n"
}
```

The whole problem with this is that the function that was returning a string value is getting the log_to_console output instead depending on the order of things. I guess this is one of those gotcha things about shell scripting that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482943/can-i-return-a-string-from-a-bash-function-without-echo-or-global-variables.

Comment: Shell functions return a value between 0-255, they cannot return a string.

Answer (score 0):

No, what's happening is that you are running your function, and it outputs two lines to stdout:

```
This is my temp file dude!
/tmp/main.4059
```

When you run it `$()`, bash will intercept the output and store it in the value. The string that is stored in the variable contains the first linebreak (the last one is removed). So what is really in your "retval" variable is the following C-style string:

```
"This is my temp file dude!\n/tmp/main.4059"
```

This is not really returning a string (can't do that in a shell script), it's just capturing whatever output your function returns. Which is why it doesn't work. Call your function normally if you want to log to console.

Comment: It might also be appropriate to send logging output to stderr (i.e. `echo "Created temp file: $TMPFILE" >&2`) -- `$()` only captures stdout.